# Jquery displaying one value even if same Id's are present in json

Tags: jquery, json

On selecting JSON object from dropdown list the values related to that object should display in textbox or a div. I am able to achieve this.. What I am looking at is..

a) When dropdown is displayed, I want Asia to be displayed only once because their Id is same. But in my fiddle, it is displayed twice.

b) I want two dropdown displayed.. for eg: When Asia is selected, in the second dropdown sites related to Asia like Singapore and kuala lumpur has to be displayed.

c)when Asia is displayed, I want the total of Singapore and kuala lumpur to be displayed in the text box, but when singapore under asia is selected, then i want only singapore's visitors to be displayed in the text box and vice versa with kuala lumpur.

I have attached my fiddle upto achieving the first dropdown.

And here is the JSFiddle `jsfiddle.net/binoymat/hjsehukf/`.

Comment: I think first you will have to loop through the items object to get rid of duplicate ids. That will solve "a". For the rest, what specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I want a jquery function to call "sites" value from json and display them in the dropdown. Now for eg:- if Asia is selected, then second dropdown should display Singapore and Kaula Lumpur and If North America is selected then second dropdown should only display texas. this is for point b

Comment: I see you have some code. Which part of the code are you having trouble with?

Comment: There is no trouble with the code. I am looking for answers to be edited on the existing code. What i mean is, for second drop down, how do i write a jquery function to get the "sites" displayed in to the second dropdown???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for

```
var items = '[{"chains": "Asia","visitors": 10,"id": 1,"site":"Singapore"},{"chains": "Asia","visitors": 20,"id": 1, "site":"kuala lumpur"},{"chains": "North America","visitors": 30,"id": 2,"site":"Texas"}]';

var checkCountry = [];
$.each(JSON.parse(items), function (k, v) {
    if($.inArray(v.id,checkCountry)  == -1){
    $("#category").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.chains + '</option>');
       checkCountry.push(v.id);
    }
});



$("#category").on('change',function () {
    var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
    var tochange = false;
    var total = 0;
    $.each(JSON.parse(items), function (k, v) {
        if(v.id == dept_number){
            if(tochange == true){
            $("#category1").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.site + '</option>');
            }else{
               $("#category1").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.site + '</option>');
                tochange = true;
            }
            total += v.visitors;
        }
    });
    $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
    $('#price-input').val(total);
}).change();   //<<<<<<<<<<<<< onload :)

$("#category1").on('change',function () {
    var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
    $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
    $('#price-input').val(price);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/hjsehukf/3/)

> Note: you have to work around with v.id and chains ,.... etc  to check
>   if its right or not .. change it up to your need

Comment: @BinoyMathew 1st you always welcome .. 2nd: check for my note in answer to check the values with v.id , site , ...etc .. 3rd: very Good Luck to you :)

Comment: Is there any way we can show the values onload of the page?? right now, when its loaded, Asia is shown, but values are not shown, so Onload of the page can we show its value???

Comment: @BinoyMathew very very simple .. just use .change();  .. updated answer ... and demo http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/hjsehukf/4/ :) .. but look it good to wrap all your code inside  $(document).ready(function(){//your code here });

Comment: @BinoyMathew have a nice day :)

Comment: @BinoyMathew I replied :)